# Android WebView VS Phone Browser

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

I've experienced a LOT of strange behaviours with using `WebView` in `Android` and I'm wondering why there are so many diffrences between the `WebView` and the `Browser`installed on each phone?

As an example, I've developed some applications that had to display `HTML` content, which contained either `jquery-mobile`, `flash`,`javascript`, YouTube embedded and so on. So I had a lot of problems with displaying this pages inside `WebViews`. Either they wouldn't get displayed at all, just blank, either the videos won't play and so on. And the strange thing is that they work properly if opened in the `Browser` installed on the phone. I had JavaScript enabled, I tried diffrent [`WebSettings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html), I had set the [`WebChromeClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) and [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) looking for javascript errors... but nothing worked.

So I got to the conclusion that the `WebView` component is completely different from the `Browser` application installed on the phones. I'm thinking that every manufacturer makes their own `Browser` to support as many as possible pages, and the `WebView` remains the standard one, included in the `Android SDK`.

Am I right? Or there is another reasons/explanation for this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Everything that @ondoteam has suggested was enabled and set at the time being. I no longer have the references to that websites, which anyway were internal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This article outlines your speculation about stock browser differences between manufacturers, that absolutely is true: [5 reality checks every team needs before working on Android webkit](http://web.archive.org/web/20120311012317/http://www.erikyuzwa.com/mobile/5-reality-checks-every-team-needs-before-working-on-android-webkit-plus-1-more/)

...which does cause trouble and mysterious/difficult to diagnose/solve problems.

As far as your issues with your `WebView` implementation:

Version of `jquery-mobile` may be an issue [jquery-mobile loaded into an android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780353/jquery-mobile-loaded-into-an-android-webview) if you are using `jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js` you may want to try the uncompressed  `jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js`

And Flash :-/ Good luck:
[Screen blinking when using a webview with flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095977/screen-blinking-when-using-a-webview-with-flash)

[Flash in WebView not working on Android 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102446/flash-in-webview-not-working-on-android-3-2)

[Flash video not displaying in WebView for Android 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1)

For loading SWF:

[Load an SWF into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview)

[loading flash files (.swf) webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915255/loading-flash-files-swf-webview-in-android)

Good luck with that, seems like a lot of variables with devices, Android versions, etc. And will take persistence with trial/error.

Comment: Great articles. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: The link for the article is broken.

Comment: @Raanan thanks for pointing that out! It seems all content for that blog blew up. I've added an archive.org copy of it, works now. Thanks again.

Comment: @TryTryAgain sorry to say, but still broken

Comment: @ItaiHanski I assume you're talking about the only link which is not a Stack Overflow link? and, it is not broken, it is a web archive link...working as expected: http://web.archive.org/web/20120311012317/http://www.erikyuzwa.com/mobile/5-reality-checks-every-team-needs-before-working-on-android-webkit-plus-1-more/

Answer (score 10):

The stock browser and WebView differs .Using all the tweaks like

```
    WebView browser;

    browser.clearFormData();
    browser.clearHistory();
    browser.clearCache(true);

    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

still it does not load high resolution images properly which is being loaded perfectly well by the android browser.
Only part of the image can be visible on the webview screen which appears fully on normal android browser.
This behavior is observed with latest Android 4X SDK as well.
Which means android default browser significantly tweaks the webkit/webview code to show any url

Answer (score 8):

`WebView` by default is restricted. You should call `setWebChromeClient` and family to have a decent browsing experience. In addition, don't forget `setJavaScriptEnabled()` and other similar stuff. Sorry for my brevity... I think that you don't need examples.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Webview is restricted? how does setting the `WebChromeClient` improve the browsing experience? it is used just for handling  JavaScript dialogs, favicons, titles, progress etc. I don't think this impacts if a webpage is loaded or not in the `WebView`.

Comment: Hello. Can I have an example URL to work with? My english is not very good, maybe "restricted" is not the best word. I mean that WebView by default is intended to show basic HTML and interact with your application but, for example, you can tweak it to show FLASH using setPluginsEnabled(). By the way I always use local resources with WebView.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this question : [jquery-mobile loaded into an android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780353/jquery-mobile-loaded-into-an-android-webview)

it might be that you're using the wrong libraries. Just check in any case.