# Again: Android Stock browser vs. WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

maybe a very easy question, but this drives me crazy...
I work in company where we develope apps based on webviews.
Everytime something went wrong, my boss tells me:
"Hey look, the page runs nicely in the android browser, so it has to run that way in the app. Make it happen." 
I know that every manufacturer has his own implementation, discussed here:
[Android WebView VS Phone Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373585/android-webview-vs-phone-browser)

But i want to keep my question simple:
Is the android stock browser a pimped webview or in other words, extends the android browser from webview-class ?
Thanks for any response?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had some issues while I was working with `turn.js`, I googled and asked on stackoverflow, most of guys told me that android stock browser is not based on webView, and worse is that webview most likely an `internet explorer` to android.

Comment: thx for your response! do you have some links maybe to your question u ask on stackverflow?

Comment: and i found this in comments, where they implemented a webview like that uses chromeview https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview