# Android 4.3 (nexus 7) Web view browser causing select inputs to be slightly cut off

Tags: android

On my nexus 7 using an in app browser (WebView) the select boxes are clipped. This doesn't happen in Chrome or Android 4.4 in an in app browser. I checked my css and I am NOT setting a height on any selects. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or have any ideas?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Nexus 7]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes phones will use a different browser for the webview than what you think it would be. I believe nexus 7 uses chrome as the default so first would be to test opening it in chrome on the nexus 7 and seeing if its still occurring.

Here is a link that describes some of the info.
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview
It also explains remote debugging which would be very helpful in seeing what is really going on.

Otherwise, there has been previous issues related to nexus phones not handling styling the way others do. The link below details a similar issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62378

Are you using phonegap? or a similar product that may be overriding the default webview?

The last thing I can think of is to write a style for the drop down so that you are guaranteeing the style no matter the device. (given its not being overridden)

EDIT - More Info
[Android WebView VS Phone Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373585/android-webview-vs-phone-browser)
You can try to change the webview to use chromewebview if available.

```
setWebChromeClient
```

Comment: My Nexus 7 is running 4.3 and the web view does NOT use chrome....Because on Chrome it looks fine. I am just using a simple Web View in Android. It looks fine on my Moto G running Android 4.4. I read somewhere that Android uses the Chrome rendering engine in Android 4.4 or later. I will give styles another look again.